# Use un-aliased module in webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

If there's a module `foo` which is aliased as `foo`:`bar`, can I then use the original (un-aliased) `foo` module for another resolution, say, `bizz`:`foo/bizz`?

```
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
  ...
  alias: {
    'bizz': 'foo/bizz',
    'foo': 'bar'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a built-in solution in webpack.

One solution is to use `path.resolve()`.

```
const path = require('path');
...
module.exports = {
  ...
  alias: {
    'bizz': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'foo', 'bizz'),
    'foo': 'bar'
  }
}
```